# ng-value doesnt submit the right value

Tags: angularjs

here's my view

```
div class="mdl-cell--12-col  chat__list" >
  <div class="mdl-cell--12-col" ng-repeat="listRoom in itemsList  track by $index">
    <ul>
   Channel name : {{listRoom[0]}}
      <li ng-repeat="x in listRoom[1]" >
         <p>MESSAGE : {{x.message_text}}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form name="haha{{$index}}">
      <input type="hidden" type="text"  ng-model="item.admin_id" />
      <input type="hidden"  type="text" ng-value="item.channel_name = listRoom[0]" ng-model="item.channel_name "/>
      <textarea ng-keydown="$event.which === 13 && addRoom()" placeholder="Type Your Message Here" ng-model="item.message_text"></textarea>
      <button  class="send__chat col-lg-2 pull-right" ng-click="addRoom()">Send</button>
       {{item | json }}
  </form>
 </div>
```

Here's example my controller

```
$scope.itemsList =[{
    "blp-crdtcrd-46": {
        "message_text": "hai",

    },
    "blp-crdtcrd-47": {
        "message_text": "halo",

    }, "blp-crdtcrd-48": {
        "message_text": "what",

    },
}];
$scope.item={};
$scope.addRoom = function(){
       $scope.item.admin_id = 1;
       $scope.item.user_id = 0;
       chatService.AddChat($scope.item);
}
```

My problem is every time i submit the form ,the ng-value of item.channel_name always submit blp-crdtcrd-48  and not dynamic,i have 3 channels in my array , and it always submit blp-crdtcrd-48 .I'm using {{ item | json }} to show the ng-value before submit and it show the corret value , when i'm hit the submit button the value result always blp-crdtcrd-48

help me and i'm appreciate all ur comment and help thank you very much

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle example so it's easier to check what's the problem

Comment: isn't `ngValue` directive for `option`/`input[type=radio]`?

Comment: my point is the ng-value of the item.channel_name in ng model always submit  blp-crdtcrd-48 every time i did submit form.it's not dynamic i have 3 channels in my array , and it always submit blp-crdtcrd-48, thanks for ur comment

Comment: @vp_art it works for input type="" also

Comment: Where you define `$scope.item`?

Comment: inside $scope.addRoom function

Comment: Of course. I guess you are not aware of this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/aa8d783cff3b43996fc69c91a40fea187153c11b/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1092